# Silverlight: Binding to data shared across viewmodels

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, binding, viewmodel, caliburn.micro

I've created a class named JsData and instantiated it in App.xaml.cs so that I can access it from multiple viewmodels. The JsData has several ObservableCollections, some properties for configuration and some methods which manipulate the process of automatically pulling data from remote server.

Now comes the question. Is it convenient for me to bind the global data to my views with minimum coding? Besides, I'm using Caliburn.Micro. Is it doable and appropriate to notify PropertyChanged events to viewmodels using messaging?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to create a service that your view models can implement.  That way on,y the view models that need the data can implement the service, and the service is more flexible because it can be injected in the view model construction.  This keep your view models more decoupled and honors the mvvm pattern.

I would not use messaging to not notify changes, that would create unnecessary overhead. You just need to have your view model implement inotifypropertychanged and then get the service in your constructor And then pass the service values to properties in your view model that raise the property changed event.

If your need help defining a service just let me know and I will post a sample

Comment: Truly messaging is a bit overhead. But the reason that I want to use a global data repository is that in my scenario the data to process isn't of small size and it actually takes quite long to conduct an iteration of data refresh in my scenario. By the way, that's an issue I haven't found any solution till now - I have to bridge the existing javascript library (synchronous), namely, to call JS from SL. I tried to wrap it asynchronously either from JS either from SL but ended in vain. It's actually ajax but the whole JS is sync-based (block until it returns). That's all I have got.

Comment: So in a word, I guess it might be less time-consuming and more affordable if the root viewmodel takes the responsibility of managing a data repository that is shared across the whole app.